# Insert a column from another table using calculated column as a key in Spotfire

Tags: join, calculated-columns, spotfire

I have two tables (A and B) that are related through the following four columns:
TECHNOLOGY - LAYER - YEAR - WORKWEEK

YEAR and WORKWEEK are calculated columns in both of the tables.

I have a column (WAFCOUNT) in table A that I want to insert into table B based off of those four related columns.

I've tried Insert->Columns, but it won't allow me to join the YEAR and WORKWEEK columns.  I know this will work if I freeze them, but I'm trying not to do that so the tables don't become embedded.

It's my goal to keep this library item as dynamic as possible.

Here's a data sample for table A.

```
TECHNOLOGY LAYER YEAR WORKWEEK WAFCOUNT
XV-15      A     2016 1        23
XV-15      A     2016 2        14
XV-15      B     2016 2        49
XV-20      A     2016 1        7
XV-20      B     2016 1        19
```

Here's a data sample for table B.

```
TECHNOLOGY LAYER YEAR WORKWEEK
XV-20      A     2016 1
XV-20      B     2016 1
XV-15      A     2016 1
XV-15      A     2016 2
XV-15      B     2016 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a 'Unique_ID' column concatenating TECHNOLOGY - LAYER - YEAR - WORKWEEK in both the tables. Using the Unique_ID column, I have added 'WAFCOUNT' column into B. Please let me know if this helps.

Below is the screenshot for your reference:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSygO.jpg)

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem.  Creating the Unique_ID column using concatenate still creates a calculated column that I have to work off of.  It's basically what I've already tried, but with an added step.  If I've misunderstood, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use a transformation instead of a calculated column from Insert>tranformations>Calculate new Column and then try to join

[image]

Comment: This looks like it's closer to what I need! Now I'm getting an error as follows: "This operation will cause a circular reference between data tables.  If you proceed, the data table B will become embedded. Continue?"

I definitely don't want to make the table embedded.  Anything I can look into to prevent that?

Comment: Try to add column from Table A to Table B but before you click Next, add the Calculate new column Transformation.